# Debugging with XDebug + PHPStorm force me to always step into

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, codeception

I am trying to debug my **Codeception** tests.

My debug platform using **PHPStorm + XDebug** is working great when using from browser with the right *IDE-KEY* as cookie.

However, when trying to debug codecept using the **CLI** I encounter the following problem:

- If I put a breakpoint in my Cest class, behavior is normal. I am able to skip functions and click "Resume" to stop debugging.
- But whenever I put a breakpoint that is in *my* code (I.E controllers or my namespace classes), xdebug becomes unusable:

> If I try to **Resume**, **Step Out** or **Step Over**, xdebug ignores my request and always **Steps Into** the current line.

This makes my testing really difficult to go on with.

I have tried using two platforms: Both my usual vagrant + nginx + php5-fpm (with remote debug), and also wamp (local debug).

Any help would be appreciated!

--

**Update:**
Well, this has nothing to do with Codeception. I tried testing just with **PHPUnit** and the same happens. Doesn't seem to be an issue with the CLI also, since I tried debugging PHPUnit from the browser, with no luck.

I thought maybe it's a PHPStorm bug, but looking at the xdebug log, I see the correct methods are called:

```
<- step_over -i 41
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_over" transaction_id="41" status="break" reason="ok">
```

step_over is called, not step_into. So maybe a bug with xdebug?

Weird thing is, this isn't always happening. After changing configurations it sometimes doesn't happen, but then the bug seems to be coming back...

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the IDE itself. I ran into the same problem using VScode with "php debug" extension. It seems that the problem is related to x-debug itself

Answer (score 9):

I ran also into a similar problem. For me, PHPStorm always jumps out, no matter what request I made.

**Removing all watches** also fixes the problem for me!

Comment: This saved my day

Comment: How is this still a problem with the IDE? This is still a problem with PHPStorm v2021.2.2.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same problem and was able to fix it by deleting the .idea directory and having PHPStorm recreate it.

This seemed like a heavy handed fix to me and after some trial and error I was able to trace the issue down to the Watches that were defined in PHPStorm.

You should be able to fix the issue by removing all your Watches.  You may need to let the current debug session finish, but the next one should work correctly.

Comment: I had the same issue except my Storm stepped out instead of stepping over (which leads to a very short debugging experience). The first thing I did after I read your solution was renaming my .idea directory. Surprisingly it worked (after I have tried several other solutions that had no effect at all).
Then I named the directory back to .idea and the problem returned.
After that, I tried to remove all my watches and voila, it worked great again.

Thank you so much for that, it was driving me nuts! <3

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar issue. PHP was running on an Ubuntu system. No matter what I did to the IDE, it just stepped out when I tried to step over, also it showed weird errors (e.g. `Call to a member function ... on unknown` - but there is no such thing as unknown in PHP, everything is either null or has a scalar type or an object type, so it made no sense.)

After some trying I updated everything on the system, including PHP and Xdebug versions and it fixed it.

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

After that it works as it should.