# Xdebug in PhpStorm doesn't break properly, steps into different files all over the place

Tags: debugging, phpstorm

I'll preface this with the following: This has been working and configured correctly for the past 6 months.

I'm trying to debug some code in PhpStorm with xdebug. Let's say I have the following code:

```
function doSomeStuff() {
  $someVariable = new SomeClass();
  $someArray = ['hello', 'goodbye'];

  foreach ($someArray as $greeting) {
    echo $greeting;
  } 
  echo 'Okay we\'re done now';
}
```

And I put a breakpoint on `$someVariable = new SomeClass();`. The breakpoint will be hit properly. If I attempt to step over, into, out of at all the debugging jumps to another file that has no relation to the next call in the stack. Step again, same thing over and over until the execution completes.

I can never step over/into and get to the line `$someArray = ['hello', 'goodbye'];`. I can, however, remove the original breakpoint and place a breakpoint on the line `$someArray = ['hello', 'goodbye'];`, reload my page and the breakpoint will be hit. Basically: if I want to get to the next line I have to stop, remove and replace my breakpoints.

Here's another peculiarity: It only happens on certain branches of my git repository. I have a branch that I've been developing for quite some time and this branch is unaffected. If I create a new branch off of that one, the new branch is affected. Also, it always jumps (incorrectly) to the same files in the same order.

I have not set any skipped paths or configured step filtering in php storm debugging.

[Here's a video of the problem](https://youtu.be/kaAOvY-q8nE)

Comment: I think that everything in normal. Just in you case your condition not met. I mean your (if ...) is false

Comment: That would actually be really hilarious (and it does look like that) but unfortunately isn't the case. I stopped the video before it was very obvious because some code in there is proprietary.

Comment: Anyway you can type your condition in console tab of debugger to see what's this condition is.

Comment: Is there a chance that what you have locally and what you have on the web/staging server is out of sync? Looking at the Xdebug remote_log may clarify things.

Comment: I/we don't have any debugging attachment to our staging servers. I can also make changes locally and the changes get executed as per normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing all watches has helped me in a similar problem.

I got the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31881698/491028).

Comment: I had this problem again today and came back to see if anyone answered. This answer solved the problem. I had a `global $someVariable` in my watches because I wanted to see if it'd work and just forgot it in there. I stopped debugging, removed it and everything worked correctly. Very annoying and unexpected.